# Python keeps running for 10+mins (after last statement in program) when there is huge (33GB) data structure in memory (nothing in swap)

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, mmap

I have need to parse a huge gz file (about ~10GB compressed, ~100GB uncompressed). The code creates data structure ('data_struct') in memory. I am running on a machine with `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v4 @ 3.20GHz` with 16 CPUs and plenty RAM (ie 200+ GB), running CentOS-6.9. I have implemented these things using a Class in Python3.6.3 (CPython) as shown below :

```
class my_class():
    def __init__(self):
        cmd = f'gunzip huge-file.gz'
        self.process = subprocess(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        self.data_struct = dict()

    def populate_struct(self):
        for line in process.stdout:
            <populate the self.data_struct dictionary>
        
    def __del__():
        self.process.wait()
        #del self.data_struct  # presence/absence of this statement decreases/increases runtime respectively
#================End of my_class===================

def main():
    my_object = my_class()
    my_object.populate_struct()
    print(f'~~~~ Finished populate_struct() ~~~~')  # last statement in my program.
    ## Python keeps running at 100% past the previous statement for 10+mins

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
#================End of Main=======================
```

The resident memory consumption of my `data_struct` in memory (RAM only, no swap) is about ~33GB. I did `$ top` to find the PID of Python process and traced the Python process using `$ strace -p <PID> -o <out_file>` (to see what Python is doing). While it is executing `populate_struct()`, I can see in the out_file of strace that Python is using calls like `mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b0684160000`  to create `data_struct`.  While Python was running past the last `print()` statement, I found that Python was issuing only `munmap()` operations as shown below :

```
munmap(0x2b3c75375000, 41947136)        = 0
munmap(0x2b3c73374000, 33558528)        = 0
munmap(0x2b4015d2a000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x2b4015cea000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x2b4015caa000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x2b4015c6a000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x2b4015c2a000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x2b4015bea000, 262144)          = 0
munmap(0x2b4015baa000, 262144)          = 0
...
...
```

The Python keeps running anywhere between 10+ mins to 12mins after the last `print()` statement. An observation is that if I have `del self.data_struct` statement in `__del__()` method, then it takes 2mins only. I have done these experiments multiple times and the runtime decrease/increase by the presence/absence of `del self.data_struct` in `__del__()`.

My questions :

1. I understanding is that Python is doing cleanup work by using `munmap()`, but unlike Python, other languages like Perl immediately release memory and exit the program. Am I doing it right by implementing as shown above ? Is there a way to tell Python to avoid this `munmap()` ?
2. Why does it take 10+mins to cleanup if there is no `del self.data_struct` statement in `__del__()`, and takes only 2mins to cleanup if there is `del self.data_struct` statement in `__del__()` ?
3. Is there a way to speedup the cleanup work ie `munmap()`?
4. Is there a way to exit program immediately without the cleanup work ?

Other thoughts/suggestions about tackling this problem are appreciated.

Comment: For 4, there is `os._exit()`, but you'll have to make sure everything you care about has already been cleaned up, buffers flushed, etc.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (using some dummy data and possibly not 33 GB of memory; it's sufficient if the cleanup takes 10 vs. 2 *seconds*). It would also be helpful if you can indicate the precise version of Python you used (is it CPython?).

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the data structure looks like.  Is it a tree, a list of records, a network of interconnected nodes, or something else?  My hunch is that it's the garbage collector.  Maybe it has to break lots of reference cycles; whereas using `del self.data_struct` takes care of most of them.

Comment: Yes, it is CPython. I will update this in the question as well.
Regarding example data : the `self.data_struct` is a `dict()` having  ~40Million keys, and each key has various Fields which in itself could be `dict()` or `list()`. I will check if I can create a dummy data example.

Answer (score 4):

Please try a more recent version of Python (at least 3.8)? This shows several signs of being a mild(!) form of a worst-case quadratic-time algorithm in CPython's object deallocator, which was rewritten here (and note that the issue linked to here in turn contains a link to an older StackOverflow post with more details):

https://bugs.python.org/issue37029

### Some glosses

If my guess is right, the amount of memory isn't particularly important - it's instead the sheer number of distinct Python objects being managed by CPython's "small object allocator" (`obmalloc.c`), combined with "bad luck" in the order in which their memory is released.

When that code was first written, RAM wasn't big enough to hold millions of Python objects, so nobody noticed that one particular part of deallocation logic *could* take time quadratic in the number of allocated "arenas" (details aren't really helpful, but "arenas" are the granularity at which system `mmap()` and `munmap()` calls are made - 256 KiB chunks).

It's not those mapping calls that are consuming mounds of time, and any decent implementation of any language using OS memory mapping facilities will eventually call `munmap()` enough times to release the OS resources consumed by its `mmap()` calls.

So that's a red herring. `munmap()` is being called many times simply because you allocated many objects, which required many `mmap()` calls.

There isn't any crisp or easy way to explain exactly when the problem shows up. See "bad luck" above ;-) The relevant code was rewritten for CPython 3.8 to be worst-case linear time instead, which gave a factor of ~250 speedup for the specific program that triggered the issue report (see the link already given).

As a comment noted, you can exit your program immediately at any time by invoking `os._exit()`, but the leading underscore is meant to scare you off:  "immediately" *means* "immediately". No cleanups of any kind are performed. For example, the `__del__` method in your class? Skipped. `__del__` is run as a side effect of deallocation, but if you actually "immediately release memory and exit the program" then *no* destructors of any kind are run, nor any handlers registered with the `atexit` module, etc etc.  It's as drastic as a program dying, e.g., with a segfault.